# Regular expression. How to get strings from text?

Tags: javascript, regex

There is a text:

```
"
Sample text 1!
,,Sample&.,? text 2?
\


-message
32 Another sample text 3
... sample text 4&
!Sample text 5%
\
```

https://regex101.com/r/LwySuM/1

In the first case, the lines are between

> "\n and \

In the second, the lines are between

> message\n and \

There can be any number of lines in between.

How can I select/get these strings in a single query?

I hope someone will write a proper regular expression.

I can do this

```
("\n|message\n)+(.*\n.*\n)
```

The text I want is in the second group but it's only for two lines. I don't know how to write a expression for any number of lines and how to add a condition that ends with

```
(\\n) or (^\\)
```

Comment: Note that Stackoverflow is [not for asking others to do your work](/help/on-topic), it's for getting help with things you've [already (re)searched](/help/how-to-ask), so: what did _you_ already try, and why did you think that might have worked, and how did that fail, _and_ what did you already try in terms of solving your problem?

Comment: So in each case you want to select everything between a pair of the first `\n` and `\` characters?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans
I know how to create the expression with a group.
For the first case:
("\n)+(.*)+(\n)+(.*)+(\n)+(\\)
The text is in group(2-5). 
But it only works for 2 lines of text.

For the second case:
(message\n)+(.*)+(\n)+(.*)+(\n)+(.*)+(\n)+(\\)
The text is in group (2-7). 
But it only works for 3 lines of text.

Comment: @FiniteLooper I presented my solution

Comment: And these are two different expressions.
I would like to make one expression.

Comment: I can do this ("\n|message\n)+(.*\n.*\n) The text I want is in the second group, but it's only for two lines.
I don't know how to write a query for any number of lines and how to add a condition that ends with (\\n) or (^\\)

Comment: @sima put that information [in your post](/help/how-to-ask), not in a comment. If you find you need to clarify things, those clarifications go in your post. No one should need to read the comments to get all the details.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I like your initial comment, do you mind if I use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"... The text I want is in the second group but it's only for two lines. I don't know how to write a expression for any number of lines ..."*

You are looking for *single-line* mode, `s`.
This is where a `.` will additionally match new-line delimiters.

The `\s+?^` here is used to skip-over the new-line delimiters, so they are not within the *capture group*.

```
/(?:-message|")\s+?^(.+?)\s+?^\\/gms
```